# Cache only part of a page in PHP

Tags: php, caching

Is it possible to cache only a specific part of a page in PHP, or the output of a specific section of code in the PHP script? It seems when I try to cache a particular page, it caches the whole page which is not want I want, some of the content in my page should be updated with every page load while others (such as a dropdown list with data from a database) only needs to be updated every hour or so.

Comment: Cache on what level using what tool / method / platform?

Comment: @Pekka Any really, I just want to minimise the amount of PHP processed and database requests I make. Also, I am using CodeIgniter, if that helps.

Comment: It would of ten minutes ago before I started answering yes. You can **never** provide too much information in my opinion in a question.

Comment: @Layke Apologies, although I don't think the framework really matters since I can try implement any sort of solution as long as it isn't _entirely_ dependant on me using a particular framework. Would you have provided a more CodeIgniter relevant solution if I did? Thanks a lot for your answer by the way.

Comment: @Layke imho your answer is still valid and add a great value to this question. I answered the same thing (with less details) because I think that answer could be useful in every context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Zend_Cache

I would probably use Zend Frameworks `Zend_Cache` library for this.

You can just use this component without needing to use the entire framework.

Step over to [Zend Framework Download Page](http://framework.zend.com/download/latest) and grab the latest.

After you have downloaded the core files, you will need to include Zend_Cache in your project.
[Zend_Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html) docs.

Have you decided how you want to cache your data? Are you using a file system? Or are you memcache? Once you know which you are going to use, you need to use a specific Zend_Cache backend.

### Zend_Cache Backends / Zend_Cache Frontends

- You need to use a backend (how you are caching in storage what it is you want to cache) and
- You need to use a frontend (how do you actually want to cache.. like using a buffer, or caching function results etc)

Backend documentation: [Zend_Cache Backends](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.backends.html)
Frontend documentation: [Zend_Cache Frontends](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.frontends.html)

So you would do something like this...

```
<?php
// configure caching backend strategy
$backend = new Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached(
    array(
        'servers' => array( array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '11211'
        ) ),
        'compression' => true
) );

// configure caching frontend strategy
$frontend = new Zend_Cache_Frontend_Output(
    array(
        'caching' => true,
        'cache_id_prefix' => 'myApp',
        'write_control' => true,
        'automatic_serialization' => true,
        'ignore_user_abort' => true
    ) );

// build a caching object
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory( $frontend, $backend );
```

This would create a cache which makes use of the `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Output` caching mechanisms.

To use `Zend_Cache_Frontend_Output` which is want you want, it would be [simple](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.frontends.html#zend.cache.frontends.output). Instead of the core you would use `output`. The options which you pass are identical. Then to use it you would:

### Zend_Cache_Frontend_Output - Usage

```
// if it is a cache miss, output buffering is triggered
if (!($cache->start('mypage'))) {

    // output everything as usual
    echo 'Hello world! ';
    echo 'This is cached ('.time().') ';

    $cache->end(); // output buffering ends

}

echo 'This is never cached ('.time().').';
```

Useful Blog: http://perevodik.net/en/posts/14/

Sorry this question took longer to write than expected and lots of answers have been written I see!

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about caching by the browser (and any proxies it might interact with), then no. Caching only takes place on complete HTTP resources (i.e. on a per URI basis).

Within your own application, you can cache data so you don't need to (for example) hit the database on every request. [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is a popular way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own caching with ob_start(), ob_end_flush() and similar functions. Gather the desired output, dump it into some file or database, and read later if conditions are the same. I usually build md5 sum of the state and restore it later.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on both what caching and view technologies are you using. Generally speaking yes, you can do something like this:

```
// if it is a cache miss, output buffering is triggered
if (!($cache->start('mypage'))) {

    // output everything as usual
    echo 'Hello world! ';
    echo 'This is cached ('.time().') ';

    $cache->end(); // output buffering ends

}

echo 'This is never cached ('.time().').';
```

taken from [Zend_Cache documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.frontends.html#zend.cache.frontends.output.examples).

Otherwise in your example you can always make a function which returns the dropdown list and implement the cache mechanism inside that function. In this way your page is not even aware of caching.

Comment: @yes123 It's not a problem, ZF is an use at will framework, just `require 'Zend/Cache.php';` and you're done. Anyway it's just a way to do that, you can achieve the same functionality even with plain php and output_buffering functions.